# What's the size of the Expo push notification token?

Tags: expo

With Expo Push Notification the token associated with the user must be stored in the backend where notifications are then being generated. This token is typically stored in a database. I couldn't find in the Expo doc any mention of the size of the token. So here is my question: what's the size of the Expo Push Notification token?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The token size is unspecified so a VARCHAR field or similar would work well in standard databases. If you need a fixed size, 1KB would likely work but it's not guaranteed and a variable-width field is safest.

Comment: A variable-width with no upper limit is typically a LOB and has a performance cost. A VARCHAR has an upper limit. You're suggesting VARCHAR(1024). Thanks for your response.

Comment: VARCHAR(1024) should be sufficient. In practice, I suspect the latency from network I/O and the HTTP/2 connection to send the push notifications will be many times the cost of whatever database format you choose.